# RN: iOS build doesn't show icons in simulator, while Android has icons (on the phone). How to fix?

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I'm web developer, new to RN, but have pet project, which was built by freelancers. Now I wanted to put some changes to the project itself and faced the issue:

iOS version built, but I see no icons there that were written in below mentioned way. Photos that are imported from Firebase are visible.

If I didn't provide any other important info - please let me know, I will attach it.

This is an example of icon code:

```
    <View style={styles.button_shadow}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onOpenFilter}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Image source={{ uri: 'filter' }} style={styles.button_icon} />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
```

Im using Xcode 12.4 and RN v.0.61.5
Will appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Could you post the code where the icon is called, and what the output should look like?
Looking at the code snippet, uri should probably not be 'location'

Comment: Sure, I've added another code example. Location and first file in xAssets folder were just random example. I do not see ANY icons in iOS build. Also attach image how it looks on Android.

Comment: Actually I changed the code snipper for filter icon, provided example on iOS and Android. Filter icon is on the top right. As You see - no icons are visible on iOS. I also provided full code example where this Filter Icon is called and example of xAssets of that Filter Icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution and the reason of the problem. Issue was that on iOS 14.4 there was a bug with React Native 0.61.5 and basically with any RN which is lower than 0.62. Upgrade or use of patches is required (if RN upgrade is not solution.